# glBindTexture invalid value possibly due to glLineWidth

Tags: c#, opengl, esri

In C#, inside the OpenGL context of Esri ArcMap dynamic display (immediate mode), I try to create textures:

```
GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
uint[] textures = new uint[1];
GL.glBindTexture(1, textures[0]);
uint error = GL.glGetError();
```

The value of `error` is 1281 (invalid value).

I've checked - it's not in between glBegin/glEnd calls, and the context is valid. I also used `GLIntercept` to check the calls and errors, but it seems to give me false negatives (I compare the full call list to the errors and the errors just doesn't match - only things like *glEnd called before glBegin* while the full function lists shows nothing like that ever happened).

I suspect it's a driver problem. I run an ATI Radeon 2400 Pro on a Win7 64 (the app is 32bit). The ESRI version I use is 9.3.1 sp1.

I've Google'd it quite a lot and even looked at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes but I can't find anything that resembles my problem.

It doesn't seem to happen in all programs that base on that code, but it happens constantly on some, so I'm really confused about it.

What should I check next?

**EDIT:**

I started eliminating code that was running before that error (long before, actually) and found that if when drawing a polygon, (a polygon that has nothing to do with that texture and that is drawn using `glVertexPointer` and `glDrawArrays`, no texture related at all), I remove the `glLineWidth` that is found before drawing that polygon, I get no error when binding the texture.

Now I know that's silly, and it makes no sense, and it's either a huge problem in the driver or in my understanding of OpenGL, but I can't figure out which :-)

I was very careful with the elimination and it's really just that line in that specific function:

```
GL.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL.glPushMatrix();
GL.glLoadIdentity();

GL.glLineWidth(someWidthParameter); // <-- The only line I comment.

GL.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

GL.glTranslate(...);
GL.glScale(...);

GL.glVertexPointer(...);
GL.glDrawArrays(...)

GL.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

GL.glPopMatrix();
GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

So now I'm even more confused than before... Any ideas?

Comment: I've read that glLineWidth() is not consistently/completely implemented across platforms. Try using a triangle strip.

Comment: Your GL error is not related to the texture stuff, and the glIsTexture behaves as expected. The texture object is not created just by the GenTextures call. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Citing the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsTexture.xml): `A name returned by glGenTextures, but not yet associated with a texture by calling glBindTexture, is not the name of a texture.` So you have to move the glIsTexture behind the glBindTexture call.

Comment: OK, but that isn't really the issue. The glBindTexture doesn't work. I only added the glIsTexture to see if I miss something, I just missed that glIsTexture won't return true unless the texture is bound, but I can't get it to bind. The only way I can get it to bind is by removing the glLineWidth call, which doesn't seem related...

Comment: I don't know why I wrote "invalid operation" since the error is "invalid value". Fixed the title now, but I still need help understanding why that happens...

Comment: Btw: Avoid using the fixed function pipeline. Stay to shaders and vertex buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

Apparently, one of the values passed to the glLineWidth was zero, which is not allowed.
The first glGetError I used was after setting that value to zero was at the bind texture, so I  thought it was related to that.

I'm ashamed it took me that long to figure that out :-)

And I certainly need better OpenGL debugging tools - apparently GLIntercept could have detect it but didn't, but since it was the only usable tool for me it had to do.

Sorry I had to bother you all and thank you for your help.